# See who deleted an answer

Tags: support, deleted-answers, undelete-request

I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21288678/neo4j-which-traversal-should-one-use) a question at SO and got an answer, which wasn't bad. Then I left work and opened my question again, to see that the answer has been deleted. A commenter (from the answer) left a comment in my question, wondering where the answer was. I'm actually wondering about this myself. Is there a way to see who deleted it and maybe why?

It may be related that the answerer had only 1 reputation, but considering this, the answer was even better. 
I know about the timeline feature, but there only seems to be my question.

Comment: *deleted by owner 1 hour ago*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters are you undeleting it? I'm not into java but that answer seems fine to me.

Comment: @rene it was actually a nice answer for a user with just 1 rep. A bit off topic, but me and another commenter was just willing to correct this.

Comment: If you thought the answer was helpful then why didn't you vote for it?  You gave him no incentive to research the changes better and update his post to make it the canonical answer.

Comment: @rene: I'm keeping out of it; no idea why the OP deleted it, could be stuff was shared that shouldn't have been or whatever.

Comment: Looks like a fair answer, voted to undelete. If its author want to delete again he can at least explain why. /cc @MartijnPieters

Comment: @UphillLuge my work time was over :). I wanted to go home, edit it a bit and accept it afterwards. I guess its not a good idea to accept an answer after a few minutes for many reasons.

Comment: It will be very nice if this answer could be brought back... thanks for the undelete votes....

Comment: I've also voted to undelete based on @RafaelT promising to edit/accept. I'm normally hesitant to undelete something that the author themselves has deleted (there has to be a compelling reason, especially where the answer doesn't appear to directly answer the question) so I'll be watching this one and casting a delete vote again if it doesn't get "improved".

Comment: Question has been undeleted.

Comment: Thank you guys! This is what makes SO so awesome.